# sql server TOP command with order by clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST

USE TEST

CREATE TABLE TBL_TEMP
(
   ID           INT,
   NAME     VARCHAR(100),
   CREATED_ON   DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP VALUES (1, 'A', NULL)
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP VALUES (2, 'B', NULL)
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP VALUES (3, 'C', NULL)
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP VALUES (4, 'D', NULL)

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM TBL_TEMP 
ORDER BY CREATED_ON
```

Result:

```
ID   NAME   CREATED_ON
------------------
 2   B      NULL
```

---

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TBL_TEMP
```

Result:

```
ID NAME   CREATED_ON
--------------------
1  A      NULL
```

Why `top 1` gives two different results, is it that when order by clause is used it picks random row and when not used then it gives proper top record ?

is it a kind of bug in sql server 2008 ?

Comment: If you use `TOP 1` **without** an `ORDER BY` - then there is **no order** guaranteeed - you'll get one, arbitrary row as your result. This is **NOT** a bug in SQL Server! `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is just pointless and should not be used ever

Comment: Both your queries are different - you have used `Order By` only for the first. So it returns the expected output. This is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not guarantee an order unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, so in the second example you get the first-inserted row by good fortune.

If you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the order is not defined if the values to sort on are identical. SQL could have selected any one of the four.

This is not a bug, but defined behaviour in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Mike, you mean to say that since the column "Created_On" has identical values that's why it is giving second or can say a random row as a result.. I got it... thanks... this sql behaviour has created a problem for me, I will find some solution...